# 2 компонента в ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день! Я первый раз пишу под Android.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: пытался в один ListView поместить 2 элемента (2 ListView). Пытался через разные лэйауты, но ничего не вышло :( Посоветуйте, как правильно это сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Вот мои элементы:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMainTwo"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:textFilterEnabled="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.95"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/listViewThree"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:id="@+id/listViewThree"
    android:layout_weight="0.27"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lvMainTwo"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Повторюсь ещё раз: в один ListView 2 элемента.

[image: Как здесь: слева текст, справа - чекбокс]

Comment: Использовать [SimpleAdapter](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter.html) или писать свой.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, но если вы и правда хотите запихнуть в список еще список, советовал бы использовать компонент ExpandableListView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По предложенному вами скриншоту:

Если речь идет о стандартных разметках , то для двух `TextView` используется `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` , вторым аргументом в адаптер передается коллекция `String` из двух позиций , которые в списке будут расположены друг под другом.

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;


map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", "Иван");
map.put("Tel", "245-45-34");
myArrList.add(map);

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", "Марья");
map.put("Tel", "456-67-78");
myArrList.add(map);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    myArrList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
    new String[] {"Name", "Tel"}, 
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Если речь идет о собственном виде отличном от предложенного , то вам нужно задать собственную разметку , где расположить элементы так , как вам требуется , присвоить первому `TextView` - `id=text1` , второму `id = text2` и подключить все это дело в адаптер (остальной код без изменений):

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    myArrList,
    R.layout.my_list_item, 
    new String[] {"Name", "Tel"}, 
    new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
```

Таких текстовых полей может быть любое разумное количество, то есть вы можете сделать 5 текстовых полей по такому же принципу (с id = text1, text2, text3, text4 и text5), определив их место на собственной разметке.
Кроме того, стандартный `SimpleAdapter` позволяет размещать и изображения

вариант разметки `my_list_item.xml` ( две надписи горизонтально ) :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1 "
    android:text="Tel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А что делать если студия пишет: "Cannot resolve symbol `put`"?