# Вывод данных в listView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Создал свою разметку для `ListView`. Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="?android:attr/alertDialogIcon"
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:maxHeight="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

А в MainActivity через адаптер из коллекции выводятся данные на данный момент в стандартную разметку

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tmpArr);
list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Как вывести данные из коллекции в `txtView` из `ListView`?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419280/177345

Comment: Вам нужен кастомный адаптер для ListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT = "text";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE = "image";

ListView yourListView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

String[] myItemText = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
int[] myItemImage= {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3}

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
myItemText.length);
Map<String, Object> m;
for (int i = 0; i < myItemText.length; i++) {
m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, from [i]);
m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, img);
data.add(m);
}

String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE};
int[] to = {R.id.imgView, R.id.txtView};

SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item, from, to);

yourListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
yourListView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, int position, long id) {

}
```